# Use Objective-C enum from swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I use SDWebImage library and there is an method that download image:

```
- (id <SDWebImageOperation>)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                                         options:(SDWebImageOptions)options
                                        progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock
                                       completed:(SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock)completedBlock {
```

The problem is that the `SDWebImageOptions` is an enum `typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, SDWebImageOptions)`

and if I call:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadWithURL(NSURL(string: video.thumbnailUrl), options: 0, progress: nil) { (_, _, _, _) in

Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'SDWebImageOptions'
```

Because I use 0 for option and it's an emun. How to solve this problem.

One more it's a pod library I can't modify sources.

Comment: Use `[]` instead of `0`.

Comment: @Sulthan, thanks!!!!!!!